# function with variable arguments -- weird output

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-functions

I have written a small C program which involves variable arguments. See below:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

double calculateAverage(int num,...)
{
  va_list argumentList;
  double sum=0;
  int i;

  va_start(argumentList,num);

  for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    sum += va_arg(argumentList,double);
  }
  va_end(argumentList);
  return(sum/num);
}

int main()
{
  printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(3,1,2,3));
  printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(4,2,4,6,8));
  printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(4,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0));
  printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(3,1,2,3));
}
```

Output is:

```
0.000000
0.000000
5.000000
5.333333
```

Only `calculateAverage(4,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0)` is giving expected output, i.e. when I specifically represent them with the decimal point.

- Shouldn't `va_arg(argumentList,double)` safely promote the numbers to double?
- How can `calculateAverage(3,1,2,3)` give 2 results in 2 different places? Am I inside some 'undefined behavior' territory? If yes, how?

I am using gcc version 4.8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't. With `va_arg()`, you tell what format the data should be assumed to have. Concerning the internal representation, `1.0` looks completely different than a `1`. And if you take a `1` as a `double`, you get something completely wrong.

Here is what happens on the stack when running your function calls:

```
double calculateAverage(int num,...)
{
  va_list argumentList;
  double sum=0;
  int i;

  va_start(argumentList,num);

  printf("%p", &num);
  unsigned char * c =  &num;
  for(i = 0; i < num * sizeof(double) + 4; i++, c++)
  {
    printf(" %02x", *c);
  }
  printf("\n");
   for(i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    sum += va_arg(argumentList,double);
  }
  va_end(argumentList);
  return(sum/num);
}
```

Then,

```
printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(3,1,2,3));
```

gives

```
0xbfc507d0 03 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 ...
-0.054776
```

whereas

```
printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(3,1.0,2.0,3.0));
```

gives

```
0xbfd15290 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 40
2.000000
```

because an integer `1` internally looks like `00 00 00 01` whereas `1.0` internally looks like `00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 3f` (both on a little endian machine).

And interpreting a stack content such as `00 00 00 01 00 00 00 02` as a double will lead to strange results.

Answer (score 2):

Issue is with this statement `sum += va_arg(argumentList,double);`

Since you are trying to interpret as `double` - the problem will happen with `Integer literals`. Cast your `int`s to `double` and it should work fine.

```
printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(3,(double)1,(double)2,(double)3));
printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(4,(double)2,(double)4,(double)6,(double)8));
printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(4,2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0));
printf("%f\n",calculateAverage(3,(double)1,(double)2,(double)3));
```

`va_arg` *cannot determine the actual type of the argument* passed to the function, but uses whatever type is passed as the type macro argument as its type.

Comment: Alternatively, you could just add decimal places to the numbers to improve readability, rather than having a number of type casts. e.g. 3 -> 3.0

Comment: @PatTeen - that would be short and sweet yes.

Answer (score 2):

The argument promotion for variable argument function follows the normal rule: types smaller than `int`(`char`, `short`, etc) are promoted to `int`; `float` are promoted to `double`, but `int` isn't going to be promoted to `double`, so this

```
 va_arg(argumentList,double)
```

tells the compiler the argument is of type `double`, but in some calls they are not. Note that you can pass `float` though, because they will be promoted to `double`.

```
calculateAverage(4,2.0f,4.0f,6.0f,8.0f);
```

The solution is either make sure you are passing `double` parameters, or use a different kind of `parmN`, for example, a format string. (Like the one of `printf`)